# How to declare variables of key and value types in a template that handles a map?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

When defining a template that handles a container such as `Set<T>, Vector<T>` you can declare variables of type `T` like this, taken from [isocpp - templates](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#overview-templates):

```
    template<class Container>
        void draw_all(Container& c)
        {
            typename Container::value_type T;
        }
```

What is the equivalent for `std::map<K,V>` to get types of key, value?

Comment: `auto` (and `decltype`) might avoid most of those needs though.

Answer (score 1):

The values used to define the map are accessible (public), can be found under **Member types** in [cppReference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (shortend list):

> ```
>  typedef _Key                        key_type;
>  typedef _Tp                         mapped_type;
>  typedef std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>  value_type;
>  typedef _Compare                    key_compare;
>  typedef _Alloc                      allocator_type;
> ```